# Istio 1.1.4 helm setup --set global.defaultNodeSelector sample

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, istio

Regarding the current installation options for `Istio 1.1.4` it should be possible to [define a default node selector which gets added to all Istio deployments](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/installation-options/#global-options)

The documentation does not show a dedicated sample how the selector has to be defined, only `{}` as value.

Currently I was not able to find a working format to pass the values to the helm charts by using `--set`, e.g:

```
 --set global.defaultNodeSelector="{cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool:istio-pool}"
```

I tried several variations, with and without escapes, JSON map, ... But currently everything results into the same Helm error message:

```
2019/05/06 15:58:10 Warning: Merging destination map for chart 'istio'. Cannot overwrite table item 'defaultNodeSelector', with non table value: map[]

Istio version 1.1.4

Helm 2.13.1
```

The expectation would be to have a more detailed documentation, giving some samples on Istio side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When specifying overrides with --set, multiple key/value pairs are deeply merged based on keys. 
It means in your case, that only last item will be present in the generated template. 
The same will happen even if you override with -f (YAML file) option. 
Here is an example of -f option usage with custom_values.yaml, with distinguished keys:

```
#custom_values.yaml

global:
  defaultNodeSelector:
    cloud.google.com/bird: stork
    cloud.google.com/bee: wallace
```

> helm template . -x charts/pilot/templates/deployment.yaml -f
>   custom_values.yaml

Snippet of rendered Istio`s Pilot deployment.yaml manifest file:

```
 volumes:
      - name: config-volume
        configMap:
          name: istio
      - name: istio-certs
        secret:
          secretName: istio.istio-pilot-service-account
          optional: true
      affinity:      
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: beta.kubernetes.io/arch
                operator: In
                values:
                - amd64
                - ppc64le
                - s390x
              - key: cloud.google.com/bee
                operator: In
                values:
                - wallace
              - key: cloud.google.com/bird
                operator: In
                values:
                - stork
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - weight: 2
            preference:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: beta.kubernetes.io/arch
                operator: In
                values:
                - amd64
```

The same can be achieved with --set:

```
--set global.defaultNodeSelector."cloud\.google\.com/bird"=stork,global.defaultNodeSelector."cloud\.google\.com/bee"=wallace
```

Comment: Nepomucen, thank you for the great sample, it's real close to the thing I tried to achieve.
I was not that clear with the "multiple values" thing, I tried to add multiple values for the same label like it is done for the beta.kubernetes.io/arch.

But as far as I can see that's not supported by the template itself.
As you have answered with an excellent sample, way better then my response I'll mark yours as the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

After searching for some hours I found a solution right after posting the question by digging in the Istio commits.

I'll leave my findings as a reference, maybe someone can safe some time that way.

Setting a default node selector works, at least for me, by separating the key by dots and escaping additional ones with \ (if there are dots in the label of interest)

```
--set global.defaultNodeSelector.cloud\\.google\\.com/gke-nodepool=istio-pool
```

To create a defaultNodeSelector for a node pool labeled with

```
cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: istio-pool
```

I was not able to add multiple values that way the {} notation for adding lists in Helm doesn't seem to get respected.